# java setting classpath for class implementing interface

Tags: java, classpath

I've problem compiling these java files .I have a class MeterMovementService.java and an interface MeterMovementServiceMBean.java . The class is implementing this interface . And i compiled the interface first .Both the class and interface resides in same package . But when I try to compile the class it gives error as :

```
MeterMovementService.java:2: error: cannot find symbol
public class MeterMovementService  implements MeterMovementServiceMBean
                                              ^
  symbol: class MeterMovementServiceMBean
1 error
```

Here is the code for the MeterMovementService.java class

My class does'nt have dependency.It just implements the interface.

```
  public class MeterMovementService  implements MeterMovementServiceMBean {
   private String message = "Sorry no message today";
   public String getMessage(){
      return message;
   }
   public void setMessage(String message){
      this.message = message;
   }
   public void printMessage(){
      System.out.println(message);
   }
   public void start() throws Exception{
       System.out.println(">>>>Starting with message=" + message);
   }
   public void stop() throws Exception{
       System.out.println(">>>>Stopping with message=" + message);
   }
}
```

Comment: how did you compile your Interface?

Comment: You need to specify the classpath (containing the classes your classes depend on) when compiling.

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: My class doesnt have any dependency. It just implements this interface

Comment: Just a suggestion - Use an IDE like Eclipse, to make your life easier. But first you should learn the basic stuffs like these.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that your class files are placed under the package folder. For e.g. if your interface is defined under package - `pkg1`, your class file should be under `pkg1` subfolder.

Your directory structure should be like this:

```
srcfolder -+
           +- pkg1 -+- MeterMovementServiceMBean.class
           |        +- MeterMovementService.class
           |
           +- MeterMovementService.java
           +- MeterMovementServiceMBean.java
```

Either you have to move the class files manually, or even better, you can compile your .java files using the below command, to let the compiler handle it all for you:

```
javac -d . MeterMovementServiceMBean.java
```

Comment: I dont have any package. all my code is directly under the srcfolder.

Comment: @winstonsanker. Any issue? I don't understand your comment.

Comment: I thought you said, both your class and interface are in same package?

Comment: @winstonsanker. If you don't have any packages for both class and interface, then there should not be any issue running the code in normal way. Are you compiling from the directory containing the java file and class file?

Comment: sorry , i meant to say that , both my class and interface are in default package . Yes , I'm running from the default package containing java file and class files.

Answer (score 1):

`javac -d . *.java` compiles all the java files in the current directory and packages the compiled classfiles according to their package structure .